# JQuery not working with Multiview

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am using the MultiView server control in one web page using Update Panel. In its second view, I have a GridView; whose first column is checkboc controls including the header.

I want to toggle the data items checkbox based on the header checkbox.

For this, I wrote a Jquery function. But the main issue is, When I try to view the page source, I was not able to find out the HTML for the second view. 

How could I toggle the checkbox using Jquery or Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't see the HTML source is that the MultiView is a ASP.NET server control and it only renders the currently selected view to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use FireBug. After you toggle the view and the HTML is updated, you'll see the current source so you can debug the jQuery.

Comment: When I move from first view to second view, then I am not able to view its HTML. Therefore, my Jquery might not be working.

Comment: Its HTML is not there for second view. HTML of only first view can be seen. I am using ASP.NET AJAX to move across the views.

Comment: FireBug will show you the updated HTML after the UpdatePanel updates. If there's no new HTML, there's an error with the UpdatePanel.

Comment: I am able to view the code now. The main reason I find out is, its not raising event when fired using Jquery syntax. I have tried the same Jquery code in separate HTML file and its work fine. Can you tell me whats going wrong in MultiView page.